# How to map a collection inside a object with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I don't know how to map 'Poses' which is inside my dto coming into my controller.

My DTO looks like this

```
public class NewInstructorProgramDto
{
    public ICollection<int> Poses { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm have an object that looks like this below where I need to map my DTO to this

```
public class InstructorProgram : BaseEntity
{
     public ICollection<InstructorProgramPose> Poses { get; set; }
}
```

where InstructorProgramPose looks like this

```
public class InstructorProgramPose : BaseEntity
{
    public int PoseId { get; set; }
    public Pose Pose { get; set; }
    public int InstructorProgramId { get; set; }
    public InstructorProgram InstructorProgram { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I map it like this

```
var newInstructorProgram = _mapper.Map<NewInstructorProgramDto, InstructorProgram>(newInstructorProgramDto);
```

and in my mapping file I need to figure out how to map all the integers for Poses to a collection of 'InstructorProgramPose' objects, where the integer is the PoseId

Here is what I have so far but this won't work because it only maps a single InstructorProgramPose, not a collection

```
CreateMap<NewInstructorProgramDto, InstructorProgram>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Poses, o => o.MapFrom(s => new InstructorProgramPose() { PoseId = s.}));
```

I think I'm on the right track with this code below

```
CreateMap<NewInstructorProgramDto, InstructorProgram>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Poses, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Poses));

CreateMap<ICollection<int>, ICollection<InstructorProgramPose>>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Select(i => i.PoseId), o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Select(i => i)));
```

but the debugger is throwing an error that says

> Exception has occurred: CLR/AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException
> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.'

**UPDATE** - Just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do in Automapper, I've included the code I used to create and fill the object without Automapper, just to show what's needed.

In my controller

```
var newInstructorProgram = new InstructorProgram() {
            Name = newInstructorProgramDto.Name,
            Description = newInstructorProgramDto.Description,
            Length = (EventLength)newInstructorProgramDto.Length,
            Experience = (Experience)newInstructorProgramDto.Experience,
            Style = (YogaStyle)newInstructorProgramDto.Style,
            Calories = newInstructorProgramDto.Calories,
            InstructorId = userFromRepo.Id
        };

        foreach(var poseId in newInstructorProgramDto.Poses) {
            var newPose = new InstructorProgramPose() { PoseId = poseId };
            newInstructorProgram.Poses.Add(newPose);
        }
        
        _unitOfWork.Repository<InstructorProgram>().Add(newInstructorProgram);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution last night so I'm posting it here.
I added an extension method to the mapping shown below

```
CreateMap<InstructorProgramForUpdateDto, InstructorProgram>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Poses, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Poses.GetInstructorProgramPoses<InstructorProgramPose>()));
```

Here is the method in the extension class

```
public static ICollection<T> GetInstructorProgramPoses<T>(this ICollection<int> poses) where T : IInstructorProgramPose, new() {
        var instructorProgramPoseColllection = new List<T>();
        foreach(var poseId in poses) {
            T pose = new T();
            pose.PoseId = poseId;
            instructorProgramPoseColllection.Add(pose);
        }
        return instructorProgramPoseColllection;
}
```